# Nth Child Calculates Differently On Different Pages?

Tags: css

I've used nth-child(3n+1) to clear every fourth element and it works fine on my category pages (ex: http://riverstarfarms.com/our-products/fruits/) but on my primary products page it's like it's calculating the fourth element wrong and clearing the third. http://riverstarfarms.com/our-products/. Any idea why it would do this?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: It was pretty basic code that I was pretty sure someone has probably encountered before. I wasn't going to post source code for two complete pages to compare them. That would've been a little over the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an article element in your ul offsetting your li count.  `nth-child(n)` only matches on the actual index of the child element, it doesn't filter based on other criteria of the selector.  Therefore `li:nth-child(2)` matches an element if it is both an li and the second child node, not the second child li.

For context, this is the HTML in question

Category Page

```
<ul class="products-list">
    <li>1st child</li>
    <li>2nd child</li>
    <li>3rd child</li>
    <li>4th child</li>
</ul>
```

Products Page

```
<ul class="products-list">
    <article>1st child</article>
    <li>2nd child</li>
    <li>3rd child</li>
    <li>4th child</li>
    <li>5th child</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is worth adding that `li:nth-of-type(2)` will actually match the correct element (although an `article` should still never appear in an `ul` of course).